# Are there specific steps to getting a matrix to reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been practicing Linear Algebra problems that require reducing a matrix to RREF and I always have so many more steps than the solution. Is there a certain order or set of rules I should be following to simplify this process?

Comment: Its called Gauß algorithm and I am sure you follow it. However, *sometimes* it may be possible to save a few steps by picking a "nice" pivot (e.g., a row other than the first row starts right away with mostly zeroes). Other than that, you cannot really worsen its complexity significantly

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you!